# Javascript Loop through Object Literal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to iterate over the below and output a string that combines the different settings:

Loop through this:

```
config : {

   settings : {
     width: 880,
     height: 495,
     byline: false,
     title: false,
     portrait: false
    }
}
```

And output:

```
var output = '&height=495&width=880&title=false&byline=false&portrait=false',
```

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know whether you explicitly want to loop, but you can simply use `jQuery.param`:

```
var output = "&" + $.param(obj.config.settings);
// I assumed `obj` contains `config`
```

The order may be different but for a query string that does not matter.

Comment: Boo jQuery -- definitely not required! :)

Comment: @editor: If you have jQuery already on the page, then why not use it?

Comment: @editor: jQuery is never *required*, but the question was tagged as such so I figured it would be the easiest solution :) @ qwertymk: Thanks!

Comment: @user906080:  qwertymk makes a good point. If you believe this is the best answer you should accept it as correct (and the same goes for any historical questions you've asked).

Comment: Somewhat new to the site. Apologize for my lack of adhering to the site guidelines. Will fix!

Comment: Is there a way that I can change one of the values when an element is clicked? For example, if I click on an element, the 'byline' changes to true, and the output variable gets updated with the new information.

Comment: @user906080: I'd say you need to update the object and call `$.param` again.

Answer (score 2):

```
var attr, val, settings = config.settings,
    output, count = 0;
if ('undefined' !== typeof settings) {
    for (attr in settings) {
        val = settings[attr];
        if (0 === count) {
            output = output + val;
        } else {
            output = output + '&' + val;
        }
        count += 1;
    }
    console.log(output);
}
```

Note, the above code adds the optimization where you don't add an `&` to the first var. I don't think you'd want that in a get var string. If you do, just change to `output = output + val;` starting from `if` to end of `else`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
function print( obj ) {
    return Object.keys( obj ).map( function ( name ) {
        return '&' + name + '=' + obj[ name ];
    }).join( '' );
}
```

Usage:

```
var output = print( obj.config.settings );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/w3D9M/